# Fieldwise distribution of Monoid, Applicative, Monad etc for Haskell records

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Is there a package that does roughly the following:

Given a record:

```
data R = R { a :: TypeA,
             b :: TypeB,
             c :: TypeC }
```

derives a lifted record:

```
data R_L f = R_L { a_L :: f TypeA,
                   b_L :: f TypeB,
                   c_L :: f TypeC }
```

and offers a couple of instances and functions similar to:

```
instance (Monoid (f TypeA), Monoid (f TypeB), Monoid (f TypeC))
         => (Monoid (R_L f)) where
  mempty = R_L mempty mempty mempty
  mplus a b = ...fieldwise mplus...

sequenceR :: (Monad m) => R_L m -> m R
sequenceR = ... run fields, sum results ...
sequenceRA :: (Applicative m) => R_L m -> m R
sequenceRA x = R <$> a_L x <*> b_L x <*> c_L x
```

and probably others. Is there a package that provides this functionality and when not, which of the mechanisms (TH? Generics?) is best to use to implement it?

Comment: That monoid instance doesn't make sense since `f` has kind `* -> *`. Could work with `MonadPlus`, is that what you mean?

Comment: Edited to make Monoid instance slightly more clear, but I would welcome MonadPlus instance also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the true open source spirit I wrote my own library:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fieldwise

https://github.com/gracjan/fieldwise

Answer (score 4):

The monoid part is possible with [generic-deriving](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving-1.5.0/docs/Generics-Deriving-Monoid.html), which offers an alternative `GMonoid`, of which generics are automatically an instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, DefaultSignatures #-}

import Data.Monoid
import qualified Generics.Deriving.Monoid as M

data R_L f = R_L { a :: f [()],
                   b :: f String,
                   c :: f () } deriving (Generic)
```

Now you can do the following:

```
*Main> let x = R_L (Just [()]) Nothing (Just ()) `M.gmappenddefault` R_L (Just [()]) (Just "foo") (Just ())
*Main> a x
Just [(),()]
*Main> b x
Just "foo"
*Main> c x
Just ()
```

(I am still figuring out the generic `Show` instance.)

An ordinary `Monoid` instance can be created as follows (thought, that might be called boilerplate again...):

```
instance (Monoid (f [()]), Monoid (f String), Monoid (f ())) => Monoid (R_L f) where
    mempty = M.memptydefault
    mappend = M.mappenddefault
```

In the package, there are also [other](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving-1.5.0) derived instances for `Functor`, `Traversable` and `Foldable`.

`Monad` and `Applicative` can maybe be modelled with generics similar to the existing instances, **if you change the kind of your type**; although, maybe not in the way you like, since, I think, they would only make sense as a *product* functor of the fields' types, and not as you propose.

Comment: Thanks for generic-deriving hint, that should be useful. Note though that your suggestion does not derive R_L from R so it is a partial solution for me.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misinterpreted/overread your use of _deriving_. I'll still leave the answer, sincy you have found it helpful.